# Getting back the class and probabilities after sorting

Tags: python

Scikit-learn's `decision_function` returns me the probabilities of different classes.

```
model= LinearSVC()
print("Probabilities are:")
predicted = model.decision_function(mat_tmp_test)
print(predicted) #value of predicted are the probabilities of different classes
```

This gives me a numpy array:

```
[[ 0.24235777  0.3219151   0.43572713     0.13572713]
 [ 0.24235777  0.3219151   0.43572713     0.53572713]
 [ 0.18263773  0.5854693   0.23189297     0.73572713]
 [ 0.3219151   0.24235777  0.43572713     0.63572713]]
```

Now I am sorting the probabilities

```
order=np.sort(predicted,axis=1)
print("Sorted!")
```

I am now trying to pick the top 2 probabilities.

```
print(order[:,-2:])
```

I get:

```
[[ 0.43572713   0.3219151 ]
 [ 0.53572713   0.43572713]
 [ 0.73572713   0.5854693 ]
 [ 0.63572713   0.43572713]]
```

How can I access the classes of the top 3 probabilities? This command is returning me an error saying the indice arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type.

```
print(model1.classes_[order[:,-2:]])
```

This should give me [1,3]
where 1,3 are the class names.

Also, is it possible to print out the probability of each class along with the classname from the code above. Something like Class A(0.90%), Class B(0.43%)?

Comment: What is the value of `predicted`?

Comment: @OrangeFlash81: Edited the question. **Predicted** consists of the probabilities of different classes.

Comment: Could you please put what `print(predicted)` prints?

Comment: Done. The rows indicate the data and columns the classes

Comment: By "top 3 probabilities", what is your expected result for this?

Comment: sorted probabilities with the top 3 among them. If it is 0.80, 0.56, 0.34, 0.22
The I should get 0.80, 0.56, 0.34 back. I have put the output in the question too.

Comment: `predict_proba` does not seem to be a method of LinearSVC() . Are you sure this is the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numpy.sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) sorts the *probabilities* in the matrix. But for accessing the class labels, you don't need the probabilities (their actual value is not of interest, but only their relative ordering). Instead, you need the *indices* of the highest probabilities.

[`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) returns an array of indices instead of values. So you should use:

```
order = np.argsort(predicted, axis=1)
print(order)
```

This will print a permutation of the indices for each row which corresponds to the sorted order:

```
[[3 0 1 2]
 [0 1 2 3]
 [0 2 1 3]
 [1 0 2 3]]
```

Now you should be able to use the indices for accessing the class labels:

```
print(model1.classes_[order[:,-2:]])
```

However, you haven't shown how `model1.classes_` looks, so you may need another indexing syntax.

To retrieve the actual probabilities, you may use the index array too:

```
predicted_sorted = predicted[np.arange(predicted.shape[0]),order.T].T
print(predicted_sorted[:,-2:])
```

Prints:

```
[[ 0.3219151   0.43572713]
 [ 0.43572713  0.53572713]
 [ 0.5854693   0.73572713]
 [ 0.43572713  0.63572713]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok,my solution is a bit convoluted.

First, create a pandas data frame so that you can have the class names there:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(predicted, columns = ['a','b','c','d']
```

Once you have that, we will iterate over the rows, sort according to the probabilities but remember the class names. For that, you can use the following:

```
import operator

def sort_and_return_names(x):
    d = x.to_dict() #convert to dictionary
    d_sorted = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) #sort by value
    keys = [i[0] for i in d_sorted] #key only the class name
    return keys
```

now you simply apply the function row-wise:

```
classes = my_df.apply(lambda x: sort_and_return_names(x), axis=1)
```

and voila, there you have your classes